# How to develop a decimal power of a sum of n terms.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I search for a way to develop or to rewrite the following expression:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^p \qquad n \in \Bbb{N} \qquad x_i, p \in \Bbb{R}_+^*$$

I suppose this is quite easy with $p \in \Bbb{N}$ but here I search for a real power.

Comment: It is not trivial for integer p.

Comment: [Multinomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem?wprov=sfla1)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain how you can get a formula for $(x+y+z)^\alpha$, and you can then think about the generalisation.

For $z=0$, we have

$$(x+y)^\alpha=\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{m}x^{\alpha-m}y^m,$$

where $\binom{\alpha}{m}:=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-m+1)}{m!}$.

Thus, we have
$$(x+y+z)^\alpha=\big(x+(y+z)\big)^\alpha\sum_{m\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{m}x^{\alpha-m}(y+z)^m=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{m}\binom{m}{n}x^{\alpha-m}y^{m-n}z^n.$$

Letting $\binom{\alpha}{m,n}:=\binom{\alpha}{m}\binom{m}{n}$, we can write

$$(x+y+z)^\alpha=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\binom{\alpha}{m,n}x^{\alpha-m}y^{m-n}z^n.$$

I note that these expansions are subject to *convergence conditions*.